# How to add a proceduaraly generated billboard to helix 3D

Tags: c#, wpf, image, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

I have a set of procedural images that I would like to add as billboards to my helix 3D application.

Currently my application looks as following:

```
public partial class _3DControl
{
    HelixViewport3D hVp3D;
    public _3DControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        createView();
    }

    public void createView()
    {
        hVp3D = new HelixViewport3D();
        var lights = new SunLight();
        lights.Altitude=40;
        lights.Ambient=0.4;
        this.Content = hVp3D;
        hVp3D.Children.Add(lights);
        this.Show();
    }

    public void  UploadBillboard(BitmapImage im, System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D position,double width,double height)
    { 
        //create material 
        var mat = MaterialHelper.CreateImageMaterial(im, 0);
        var bboard = new BillboardVisual3D();
        bboard.Material = mat;

        //set coordinates 
        bboard.Position = position;
        bboard.Width = width;
        bboard.Height = height;

        //add the billboard 
        hVp3D.Children.Add(bboard);
    }
```

However when I call the function to add a billboard:

```
           HelixLinker.GetHelix().UploadBillboard(((Bitmap)e).bitmapToBitmapImage(), 
new System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D(0, 0, 0), 100, 100);
```

Then I see nothing being added, any idea what I' m doing wrong?

I also tried with the RectangleVisual3D class.

```
public void UploadRect(BitmapImage im, System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D position, double width, double height)
        {
            var mat = MaterialHelper.CreateImageMaterial(im, 0);
            var bboard = new RectangleVisual3D ();
            bboard.Material = mat;
            bboard.Width = width;

            hVp3D.Children.Add(bboard);
        }
```

Which if execuded in the same way results in a (promising) image [image] however in this case the material appears not to be properly set.

Note: I hope that the BillboardVisual3D is the right class, I'm working on something that will allow me to put image "on the floor" so to speak, I want to have flat images that don't have a depth and allow for transparancy.

Comment: Any ideas for futher information feel free to ask (this is the first thing I' m doing with Helix and as such I have no idea what information is important).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you set the Opacity to 0? Then you wont see anything.

Try this:

```
//create material 
var mat = MaterialHelper.CreateImageMaterial(im);
```

See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Media.Brush.Opacity);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

Edit:

Sorry, my bad with the string. But this ist working for me:

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateBilboard();
    }

    private void CreateBilboard()
    {
        BitmapImage im = new BitmapImage(new System.Uri(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Lighthouse.jpg"));

        var mat = MaterialHelper.CreateImageMaterial(im, 1);
        var bboard = new BillboardVisual3D();
        bboard.Material = mat;

        var position = new System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D(0, 0, 0);
        var width = 100;
        var height = 100;


        //set coordinates 
        bboard.Position = position;
        bboard.Width = width;
        bboard.Height = height;

        //add the billboard 
        viewPort.Children.Add(bboard);
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="BillboardImageMaterialDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ht="clr-namespace:HelixToolkit.Wpf;assembly=HelixToolkit.Wpf" 
        Title="BillboardImageMaterialDemo" Height="480" Width="640">
    <Grid>
        <ht:HelixViewport3D x:Name="viewPort" ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True">
            <!-- Remember to add some lights -->
            <ht:SunLight/>
        </ht:HelixViewport3D>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image: Bildboard with the lighthouse]

Comment: var mat = MaterialHelper.CreateImageMaterial(im); doesn't work as im isn' t a string. Setting opacity to 1 didn' t work either (same result)